# Getting NaN when attempting to increment score

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to currently trouble-shoot the following code:

```
function getStuff(){
  document.querySelector('#tuna').onclick=scorefunc;    
}

function scorefunc() {
  var scorep;
  scorep = scorep + 1;
  document.getElementById("scorez").innerHTML = "You have found me: " + scorep + " times";
}
```

Basically, when the user clicks the paragraph element (p) with id tuna, scorefunc runs. I am trying to add 1 to the score every time it is clicked but instead, it says "You have found me NaN times"

My HTML code looks like this if that is what is wrong:

```
<p id ="scorez">You have found me: </p>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `scorep` starts out `undefined`. You can't add 1 to `undefined`, it'll give you `NaN`

Comment: Wow silly me! Appreciate it, man! Fixed by setting var scorep = 0;

Comment: Also, if scorep is defined as 0 inside the function, it will be reset to 0 everytime the function is called. So move your scorep initialization to outside the function :)

Comment: Was just working on that Syndey haha! Thank you. Was confused on local/global since I'm used to python and your suggestion fixed it

Comment: Python uses the exact same scoping: https://ideone.com/xZvqTZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `scorep` is `undefined`. You declare it (i.e. `var scorep`), but you never define it, so you are literally trying to add `undefined` and `1` together, which of course produces `NaN`.

Change your declaration to `var scorep = 0` to fix the problem.

Further, if you want `scorep` to increment by 1 every time the `p` element is clicked, you are going to have to either create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) or declare the variable outside of the local scope.

```
var scorep = 0
function scorefunc() {
  scorep += 1
  document.getElementById("scorez").innerHTML = `You have found me: ${scorep} times`
}
```